# When installing phpmyadmin, when and where is the MySQL application password used?

Tags: phpmyadmin

When installing phpmyadmin (ubuntu) we are asked for a MySQL application password.

All of the articles I found say to use the same as the MySQL root password but I like to keep things separate.  So when and where is this application password used?

Related also is the login page (.../phpmyadmin), is this asking for the MySQL user and password or a phpmyadmin user and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the password you're asking about is used for the controluser to connect to MySQL (the controluser is an administrative user phpMyAdmin uses to handle some advanced features like bookmarked queries, relation view, and user-level permissions). If I'm right (it's been a while since I've done that installation, but I can't imagine what else it would have asked about), you don't normally need to use that password for anything. It's just a system-level thing used for the applications to communicate.

About your second question, you use your MySQL username and password when connecting. There aren't any specific phpMyAdmin users or groups; it just passes along whatever you enter to MySQL.